# Can I set spine and ticks in rcParams?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tend to use the following axes options in my Matplotlib (v1.3.1) plots:

```
        ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)  
        ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(True)  
        ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)  
        ax.spines["left"].set_visible(True)  

        ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  
        ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()  

        ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off",  
                labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")
```

This works fine after grabbing the current axis, but I was wondering whether I could make all this default behaviour by setting things in `rcParams`?

Comment: So, it would appear that this is [not currently possible](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Plotting-style-tp45034p45071.html). Any tips on how I could streamline things a bit?

Comment: The helper function in the answer to that question looks perfectly handy to me. Put it in your module of utility functions.

Comment: @cphlewis That's what I have right now, a function that cleans up the axis, but it would be really nice to have it as a default, rather than having to remember to call this function everytime

Comment: Just for those seeing this old question: The option to set spines and ticks via [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) is present in any newer matplotlib version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment, this is now possible:

```
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.top'] = False
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.bottom'] = False
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.left'] = False
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.right'] = False
```

For multiple `rcParams` use a `dict`:

```
plt.rcParams.update({'axes.spines.top': False, 'axes.spines.right': False})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and have, between this answer and have found the following:

Matplotlib 1.3.1 does *not* recognize any of these inputs as rcParams:

```
>>> plt.matplotlib.__version__
'1.3.1'
>>> plt.rcParams['axes.spines.top'] = False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Software\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 811, in __setitem__
    See rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters.' % (key,))
KeyError: 'axes.spines.top is not a valid rc parameter.See rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters.'
```

Matplotlib 1.5.1 does, however:

```
In[1]: from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
In[2]: plt.matplotlib.__version__
Out[2]: '1.5.1'
In[3]: plt.rcParams
Out[3]: 
RcParams({u'agg.path.chunksize': 0,
          [...]
          u'axes.spines.bottom': True,
          u'axes.spines.left': True,
          u'axes.spines.right': False,
          u'axes.spines.top': False,
          [...]
In[4]: x = np.linspace(0, 6)
  ...:     y = np.sin(x)
  ...:     plt.close('all')
  ...:     plt.plot(x,y,'k-')
```

[image: Figure with axes.spines deactivated for top and right edge in matplotlibrc]

To remove the ticks as well, I had to removee them after the fact, using `ax.tick_params(top="off",  right="off")`. I did not find anything related in `rcParams`.

I also tested matplotlib 2.2.3. There, the `axes.spine.*` and got no ticks on the top and bottom without specifying any additional parameters. Either the entries in the matplotlibrc remove the whole axis, including tick marks, or the new `ytick.right`, `xtick.top` entries in the `rcParams` dictionary are defaulting to `False`

[image: The same figure with matplotlib 2.2.3, using the same matplotlibrc]

Unfortunately, that still hides the last gridline on the right-hand side if it is exactly at the edge, even though the top gridline is shown under the same circumstances.

==> in other words:

- version 1.3.1 does not have a global switch and needs `ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)` applied.
- 1.5.1 can remove the lines, globally, using the method Dan suggested (set `axes.spine.top` and `axes.spine.right` to  `False`), but not the ticks, which still need the `ax.tick_params()` command
- still later versions (not sure which version introduced it) also have `ytick.right` and `xtick.top` settings which can be set to `True` or `False` to also omit the ticks on those edges.