# How to remove axes and ticks from opposite edge of pyplot axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make my plots look like this:
[image: Plot with axis lines on bottom/left, and ticks only on those bottom/left axis lines]

That is:

- Solid lines at the left/bottom edge for the plot axes, but not a closed box
- Ticks only on the axes, not on the opposite edge.

[This question and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899736/can-i-set-spine-and-ticks-in-rcparams) provide two pieces of information:

1. Those lines are called "spines"
2. They can be deactiveted separately via `axes.spines.<xxx>`

However, that does not seem to work on my end:

```
>>> plt.matplotlib.__version__
'1.3.1'
>>> plt.rcParams['axes.spines.top'] = False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Software\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 811, in __setitem__
    See rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters.' % (key,))
KeyError: 'axes.spines.top is not a valid rc parameter.See rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters.'
```

Removing the spines after the fact seems to work though:

```
>>> ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False) 
>>> ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
```

So the best I've achieved so far is this:
[image: same plot, but there are tick marks on all four edges]
This still has all the tick marks and is missing a grid line at the right edge (but interestingly enough not at the top)

How can I have the ticks just one one side, too?

I've seen pyplot plots with ticks on one side ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75atb.png), from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245152/pyplot-plot-a-curve-with-ticks-on-one-side)) but have not been able to figure out how to do this. All the tick settings I've found so far only specify width, length, position (along the axis, in/out), or turn them all on/off.

Ideally, I'd like to achieve this by creating a modified `matplotlibrc`, so I can just load that and have everything use the same style.

I'm still on matplotlib 1.3.1 (not my choice but hard to change now). If I had to, I could save the data and process it in an up-to-date version, though I'd prefer to avoid that.

Comment: `ax.spines['right'].set_visble(False)` and `ax.spines['top'].set_visble(False)`

Comment: My question was not quite answered in the duplicate and, most importantly, the fact that the axis lines are called "spines" was unknown to me, and probably the reason I had not found that answer. I've summarized my findings as a new answer to that question, to keep things in one place.

Comment: Well, version 1.3.1 of matplotlib is very ancient (the linked post is 6 years old and `plt.rcParams['axes.spines.top'] = False` already worked back then.  StackOverflow isn't very suited to cope with such a large range of versions, especially as installing a new version is quite easy, and a huge amount of related libraries also improved a lot in the meantime.

Comment: To display the full grid, `ax.grid(clip_on=False)` might work, but I really don't have an idea about matplotlib 1.3.1.